# how to select the li that has been clcked but not its possible parents or childrens?

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

Is it possible in a nested menu to have a jquery selector for the very li that's been clicked but not its possible parents or children?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toc > ol > li:first-child').addClass('selected');
  $('.toc > ol > li').on('click', function() {
    console.log('ee');
    //$('.toc').find('li').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.toc .selected a {
  border-left: 4px solid #22BBEA;
  color: #22BBEA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toc'>

  <ol class="circle">

    <li class="">
      <a href="#description-de-l-outil">1- Description de l'outil</a>
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
      <a href="#les-prealables-a-son-utilisation">2- Les préalables à son utilisation</a>

      <ol class="circle">

        <li>
          <a href="#1-plateforme-amu-hal">2-1 Plateforme AMU HAL</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#2-site-drupal">2-2 Site drupal</a>
        </li>

      </ol>

    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#les-fonctionnalites-disponibles">3- Les fonctionnalités disponibles&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#notice-a-l-usage-des-gestionnaires-de-site">4- Notice à l'usage des gestionnaires de site</a>
    </li>
  </ol>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you firstly need to attach the handler to all the `li` elements in the HTML, not just the top level `ol > li`. Then you can call `stopPropagation()` on the event to stop it bubbling up the DOM and affecting the parent `li` elements. Finally, you need to remove the `selected` class from every element, not just the `siblings()`, as they may not be at the same level any more.

To exclude the children, you need to amend the CSS to reset the styles on them, using a `.toc li.selected li a` selector.

With that said, try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toc > ol > li:first-child').addClass('selected');
  
  $('.toc li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.toc a,
.toc li.selected li a {
  border: 0;
  color: inherit;
}

.toc .selected a {
  border-left: 4px solid #22BBEA;
  color: #22BBEA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toc'>
  <ol class="circle">
    <li class="">
      <a href="#description-de-l-outil">1- Description de l'outil</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#les-prealables-a-son-utilisation">2- Les préalables à son utilisation</a>
      <ol class="circle">
        <li>
          <a href="#1-plateforme-amu-hal">2-1 Plateforme AMU HAL</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#2-site-drupal">2-2 Site drupal</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#les-fonctionnalites-disponibles">3- Les fonctionnalités disponibles&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#notice-a-l-usage-des-gestionnaires-de-site">4- Notice à l'usage des gestionnaires de site</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```